# Unable to browse to apache service, Service is running

Tags: apache-2.2, http, centos6, port-forwarding

### Summary

I have a very peculiar problem. I am not able to open the "It Works!" page after installing a fresh server with apache. I am able to ssh to the box (from outside the network). Apache seems to be running on my Centos6.4x86_64 box just fine. Nothing useful in /var/logs/httpd/*. What am I missing?

### The setup

I am outside the network right now. The "server" is a VM on my home computer running bridged mode.

public ip: A.B.C.D

Host: 192.168.1.5

VM: 192.168.1.8

I have a verizon fios router that is forwarding ports 22, 80, and 8888 to the VM. I am able to ssh over port 22, but I am not able to browse to the public URL over port 80. so A.B.C.D:22 is working, but http://A.B.C.D:80 is not.

### What I've tried

nmap to see if it is listening:

```
nmap -sT -O localhost

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-10-25 11:10 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000040s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

I tried going to it locally (lynx) and it does work. So, is the problem in my ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for iptables config.
Only 22 port is usually opened by default on local firewall.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! For those of you playing at home, that's: 

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT